# Kafka Stream timestamp synchronization in KStream/KTable join

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Having an inner join KStream/KTable with the following sequence of messages:

***table_evt_at_t1 --> stream_evt_at_t2 --> table_evt_at_t3 --> stream_evt_at_t4***

the join triggers:

***(stream_evt_at_t2, table_evt_at_t1) + (stream_evt_at_t4, table_evt_at_t3)***

So far, everything ok. 
The unexpected result comes up when I reset the stream application (with kafka-streams-application-reset.sh) and replay all the events:

***(stream_evt_at_t2, table_evt_at_t3) + (stream_evt_at_t4, table_evt_at_t3)***

It seems that Kafka Stream doesn't take into account the timestamps when processing the events. It populates the Ktable and then it processes the KStream getting the last value of the Ktable (table_evt_at_t3) for the two KStream events.

Note that I am using Kafka Streams 2.3.1, a custom TimestampExtractor and the property `max.task.idle.ms = 10 * 1000L` as [KIP-353][1] suggests

Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: What you describe is not expected behavior. Processing should happen in timestamp order and the original result should be the output for the reprocessing case, too. There are some known corner cases with regard to timestamp synchronization though, that are not fixed yet -- however, I would actually not expect that you hit any of those (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7458 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8478). Can you reliable reproduce the issue? Or does it sometime work correctly, but sometimes not?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax It fails always. Note that I'm testing with 1 broker, 1 partition per topic, num.stream.threads = 1 (default) and 1 application running Kafka Streams. It's so weird

Comment: Actually, the scenario is not exactly as I mentioned in question (KStream/KTable join). I have a KStream/KStream join first and the a KStream(previous join)/KTable join. Removing the first KStream/KStream join, everything works. It seems that the issue is in KStream/Kstream join...

Comment: Timestamp synchronization happens at the source level. Is there a repartition topic in between (ie, does the key change)?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Yes, there is a key change. Concretely, before and after the KStream/KStream join there are two "selectKey".

Comment: For this case, timestamp synchronization should happen between the repartition topics. Hence, you might actually be subject to one of the bootstrapping bugs... Can you try to increase `max.task.idle.ms` to be larger than the commit interval?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Having max.task.idle.ms > commit.interval.ms fails equally. I worked-around for my use-case changing the order of joins. First KStream/KTable and then KStream(result of the first join)/KStream (which creates the repartition topic). Thank you very much for your help Matthias.

Comment: Glad you found a workaround -- however, it's still unclear why it does require the reordering...

Answer (score 0):

- The first result that join triggers is expected behavior since KStream-KTable joins are not windowed but timestamped
- The result after a 'reset'/replay is also expected behavior since KTable only keeps latest value for a given key and "table_evt_at_t3"("table_evt_at_t1" is already overwritten) is the last value